# Can I make label(via code) and make it disappear after few seconds?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I want to use label as notification for few events. If Function started, it makes one label and display notification. And I want it disappear automatically in few seconds. I was thinking I can use Timer(by make timer and make it turn label.visible to false), but it was not worked. How can I make this one? 
This is my code(Don't mind footnote).

```
Private Sub Notif(message As String, critical As Integer)
    Dim notification As New Label '레이블 생성
    Me.Controls.Add(notification) '컨트롤에 추가
    notification.Text = message '텍스트 Apply
    If critical = 0 Then '일반이면
        notification.BackColor = Color.Black '블랙 적용
    Else
        notification.BackColor = Color.Red '크리티칼 하면 레드 적용
    End If
    notification.Font = New Font("HelveticaNeueLT Pro 65 Md", 12, FontStyle.Bold) '폰트 적용
    notification.Location = New Point(25, 10 + 50 * EisFuncNotiCount) '위치 적용
    notification.Size = New Point(460, 44) '크기 지정
    notification.Tag = EisFuncNotiCount
    EisFuncNotiCount = EisFuncNotiCount + 1
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: Creating a new `Label` seems a bit silly. Why not just add a single `Label` in the designer and then change its `Text` and `Visible` properties as required? Also, yes, you would use a `Timer` to hide the `Label` after a particular period of time. As you have posted no code trying to do that, you haven't encountered an issue doing that yet, so there's no problem to solve.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Of course I already tried that. But I wonder how can I make label visible=false because there's no name with the label I made that can usable in other sub.

Comment: If you did what I said and just used one `Label` added in the designer then there would be a name, so there would be no issue. You're trying to solve a problem you created yourself.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thank you for advice, but I needed to make one label per one notification NOT using single label for multiple notifications. I solved my problem via my code using .name property and timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Task.Run

```vb
Private Sub Notif(message As String, critical As Integer)
    Dim notification As New Label '레이블 생성
    Me.Controls.Add(notification) '컨트롤에 추가
    notification.Text = message '텍스트 Apply
    If critical = 0 Then '일반이면
        notification.BackColor = Color.Black '블랙 적용
    Else
        notification.BackColor = Color.Red '크리티칼 하면 레드 적용
    End If
    notification.Font = New Font("HelveticaNeueLT Pro 65 Md", 12, FontStyle.Bold) '폰트 적용
    notification.Location = New Point(25, 10 + 50 * EisFuncNotiCount) '위치 적용
    notification.Size = New Point(460, 44) '크기 지정
    notification.Tag = EisFuncNotiCount
    EisFuncNotiCount = EisFuncNotiCount + 1

    '--------------------------------
    Task.Run(Sub()
                 Task.Delay(3000).Wait() ' 3초 기다림
                 Me.Invoke(New Action(Sub() ' 크로스 스레드 오류 방지
                                          notification.Visible = False ' Visible 속성을 False로 변경
                                      End Sub))
             End Sub)
    '--------------------------------
End Sub
```